# How to ditch Babel from Vue build chain?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I'm developing a Vue app solely for Chrome, which leads me to believe (please correct me if wrong) that I can write native ES6 and don't need to transpile.

The Vue CLI generates a package.json like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^13.0.1",
    "browserify-hmr": "^0.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.6",
    "envify": "^3.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^2.1.2",
    "uglify-js": "^2.5.0",
    "vueify": "^9.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      "babelify"
    ]
  }
```

But if I remove the 4 references to Babel, I get compile errors on my very first file. So really I just have two questions:

1) Am I correct in thinking that I can ditch Babel?
2) How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think `browserify` can handle `ES6 imports` without `Babel`. Usually, you could just get away with using something like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com) to `uglify` and `minify` without transpiling, because `browserify` is intended to allow `require` to be used in the browser, but if the browser supports `import` then you don't really need it. Unfortunately, this means that you won't be able to use `vueify`, so you lose the ability to use `single file components`, so I guess it's down to whether you think that `trade-off` is acceptable.

You may be interested in this discussion on GitHub: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/1186

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, until browserify (or the the browser itself) can handle ES6 imports, I'm stuck with ES5?

Comment: I think it will only be ES5 `requires` that you need to use, you should still be able to use `ES6` for everything else, just replace `import` with `require` and you should be fine. It looks like `chrome` doesn't support `import` yet anyway, so I think that trade-off is acceptable.

Comment: Or, you could tell Babel to only transpile your ES6 modules to CJS modules: [`babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/).

Comment: @daninthemix Any update on this in the last 3 years? Were you ever able to remove Babel from your Vue build process?